# original function been called instead of spied function in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have given up on what I feel is simple. I have the following promise:

information.js

```
// other methods

export async function information() {

  let info= {
    code: ''
  };
  await AsyncStorage.multiGet([
    'code'
  ])
    .then((response) => {
      info['code'] = response[0][1]

    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  return info;
}
```

process.js:

import { information } from "../information"

```
Promise.all([information()]).then(function (values) {

  if (values[0]['code'] != null) {
    // tag the code
  }
}).catch(err=>{
  console.log(err)
});
```

now in processor.test.js

```
import * as info from '../information';

it("should tag service code", async () =>{

  const spy = jest.spyOn(info,"information")
  spy.mockResolvedValue({'code':'ABC'})
  expect(tagCode()).toEqual('ABC_Y')

});
```

it fails saying expected 'ABC_Y' but got null. From console.log on the resolved Promise, I can see it is executing the original information method, instead of my spy thus returning null always.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm on the wrong track, however could this be solved by changing your test case slightly?

```js
jest.spyOn(info, 'information').mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn(async () => { code: 'ABC' });

expect(tagCode()).toEqual('ABC_Y');
```

I haven't tested this code, just my opinion at 4:42am.

I opt to include a jest.fn call within my mockImplementation call, this allows me to test for other things such as information() being called:

```js
expect(info.information).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(info.information).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ code: 'ABC' })
```

Hope this goes at-least some way toward helping you resolve your issue, although I'll admit I've had many an issue with Jest (especially with dependencies, although these are usually my mistake through context issues).

I've read your question a few times and I'm still not convinced I truly understand it, so please accept my apologies if above is useless to you.

```js
export async function information() {

  let info= {
    code: ''
  };
  await AsyncStorage.multiGet([
    'code'
  ])
    .then((response) => {
      // this may produce different results
      info['code'] = response[0][1]

    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  return info;
}
```

An issue could be above, you're returning `info`, I'm assuming with the understanding it could contain the resolved value, from your `.then` statement, as far as I'm aware this wouldn't work in reality.

The `.then` is processed at the end of the method (after `return`), so your `info` could contain an empty `code`, then some time after would complete the Promise.

I'd change that from above, to:

```js
export async function information() {

  let info= {
    code: ''
  };
  await AsyncStorage.multiGet([
    'code'
  ])
    .then((response) => {
      info['code'] = response[0][1]
      Promise.resolve(info);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Although I'd recommend not mixing async/await with Promises, as it's a pretty good way to shoot yourself in the foot (my opinion of course).

You can test this theory of course by inserting a comment above your `return` and inside your `.then`, a simple `console.log('called') | console.log('called1')` will give you an indication of which was called first.

Comment: Thanks so much @Isolated. It looks promising. Will check it out and get back to you. I appreciate the reply.

Comment: Thanks Isolated. I have found the problem finally but great tip on the promise inside async. The issue was the implementation itself and not the mocking. Fyi, you had a tiny typo...spyOn.

Comment: @elimey no problem at all! I've corrected the typo also! I'd always encourage sticking to either Promise or async/await depending on your preference.

Glad you got it working though, all the best.